# Not getting localstorage data without page refresh in react project

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

When I get back to registration page i need to refresh page,after registration i need to refresh to show login page,and when login page comes up i need to refresh again to get localstorage data.Then login works.Again in home page to show data.May be data sending or getting from localstorage is not okay ,but don't know solution.

register.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link,useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const Regiter = () => {
    const[username,setUsername]=useState('')
    const[email,setEmail]=useState('')
    const[location,setLocation]=useState('')
    const[password,setPassword]=useState("")
    const[confirmPassword,setConfirmPassword]=useState("")
   const dispatch=useDispatch();
   const navigate=useNavigate()
    const register=(e)=>{
        if(username===""){
            alert("Provide Username")
        }else if(email==="" && !email.includes("@")){
            alert("Invalid Email")
        }else if(location===""){
            alert("Provide Location")
        }else if(password.length<5){
            alert("Password must be 5+ character")
        }
       if(username && email && location && password && confirmPassword ){
        dispatch({
            type:"REGISTER",
            payload:{
                id:(new Date()).getTime(),
                username,email,password,location
            }
        });
        localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify({
            users:[
                username,
                email,
                password,
                location
            ]
        }))
        alert("Registered")
        navigate("/login", { replace: true });
       }
    }


 return (
            <form className=''>
                <div className="bg-grey-lighter min-h-screen flex flex-col drop-shadow-lg">
                    <div className="container max-w-sm mx-auto flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-2">
                        <div className="bg-white px-6 py-8 rounded shadow-md text-black w-full">
                            <h1 className="mb-8 text-3xl text-center">Regsiter</h1>
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
                                autoComplete='usename'
                                name='username'
                                placeholder="User Name"
                                onChange={(e)=>setUsername(e.target.value)} />

                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
                                autoComplete='current-email'
                                name='email'
                                placeholder="Email" 
                                onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>

                            <input 
                                type="password"
                                className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
                                autoComplete='new-password'
                                name='password'
                                placeholder="Password"
                                onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                            <input 
                                type="password"
                                className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
                                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                name='confirm_pass'
                                onChange={(e)=>setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                                {password!==confirmPassword&&<small key={email+password} className="text-red-700">Not Matched</small>}
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"
                                placeholder="Location"
                                name='location'
                                onChange={(e)=>setLocation(e.target.value)}/>

                            <input
                                type="button"
                                className="w-full text-center py-3 rounded bg-green-600 text-white hover:bg-green-dark focus:outline-none my-1"
                                value="Submit"
                                onClick={register}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="text-grey-dark mt-6">
                            Already have an account? 
                            <Link className="no-underline border-b border-blue text-blue-800 px-2" to="/login">
                                Log in
                            </Link>.
                        </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </form>
    )
}
```

export default Regiter

reducer.jsx

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore} from 'redux'

const initialState=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))||{
    users:[]
}
console.log(initialState);
const reducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){

        case "REGISTER":
            return{
                ...state,
                users:[...state.users,action.payload]
           
    }
    case "LOGIN":
            return{
                ...state,
                users:action.payload
           
    }
    case "LOGOUT":
            return{
                users:null
           
    }
    default:return state;
}
}
export default createStore(reducer)
```

Comment: since reducer ins't a component, you should rename the reducer file. From reducer.jsx to reducer.js

Comment: Did it ,but not working ...

Comment: what do you get when you log the initial state?

Comment: Array of user data...

Answer (score 0):

Use `useSelector` hook from `react-redux` to update your component when store state changes.

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

To give you the solution:

After you register the user, navigating to '/' where you render the registered user you can implement it as

```js
const Home = () => {
  // Return the state corresponding to what you want to display. 
  // In this case, I am considering user as my state stored in the redux-store. 
  const user => useSelector(state => state.user)

  return user ? <div>{user.name}</div> : <div>No user found</div>
}
```

Follow Up points:

1. Try to use [@reduxjs/toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) in place of redux as it is preferred these days.
2. You are setting users as an array of all user-details when storing to localstorage after registering, but dispatching a payload object which appends the object an element to the array of user details. Not sure what is happening around here.